# How use jQuery Mobile with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(jQuery.mobile !== undefined && 'good'); // prints 'good'!
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/comp/pages/Index.js" src="/Scripts/require.js></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(jQuery.mobile !== undefined && 'good'); // prints 'good'!
</script>
```

But in my `Index.js`, the `jQuery.mobile` disappears:

```
require([], function (view) {
    console.log(jQuery.mobile === undefined && 'undefined!'); // prints 'undefined!'
});
```

How do I bring `mobile` back to `jQuery` ? (I obviously don't care about having **some** `mobile` in `jQuery`, but interested in using `jQuery Mobile` with `RequireJS`.. just to make it clear..)

### Edit 1:

I tried to add `require` to Index.js:

```
console.log(jQuery.mobile === undefined && 'undefined!'); // prints 'undefined!'
require(['/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js', '/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js'],
    function (jQuery,jqm, view) {

    console.log(jQuery.mobile === undefined && 'undefined!'); // prints 'undefined!'
});
```

Comment: Does it logs undefined to throws an undefined exception? does jQuery defined inside your function?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask correct: Does it logs undefined OR throws an undefined exception?

Comment: @Naor: it logs: `console.log(jQuery.mobile === undefined && 'undefined!');`. again, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my workaround, since up to date, I found no solution to it: I save the global `jQuery` object/function right after including it in the `HTML`, in a global variable `myGlobalObject`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="content/jqm/jquery.mobile-min.css"/>
<script src="content/jqm/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="content/jqm/jquery.mobile-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--jQuery RequireJS issue workaround:-->
<script type="text/javascript"> window.myGlobalObject = { jQuery:jQuery }; </script>
```

And then I define new file, `jq.js`, that returns this global object in the form that `RequireJS` is familiar with:

```
define(function(){
    return myGlobalObject.jQuery;
});
```

And whenever I need it, I use this "intermediate" module:

```
require(['/content/jq.js'], function ($) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you manage to load index.js?
RequireJS adds .js to a file so instead of `/comp/pages/Index.js` you should use
`/comp/pages/Index`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="/comp/pages/Index" src="/Scripts/require.js></script>
```

Comment: I believe that RequireJS is smart enough to handle if the .js extension is present.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've setup RequireJS and jQuery correctly.

In your Index.js file you need to require the jQuery and jQuery mobile files; for example:

```
require ("/Scripts/jquery");
require ("/Scripts/jquery.mobile");
```

I will also point out that you should rename your files so that version numbers are not included in the filename - this will allow you to update to newer releases without having to change your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try an older version of jQuery Mobile to start with.

jQuery 1.8.2 won't work with RequireJS, and it can be the case with the latest version of jQuery Mobile as well.

You also have to make sure you require the jQuery and jQuery mobile JS files in your code.

I think you should check out this thread:
[How do I use requireJS and jQuery together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535926/requirejs-and-jquery)

Rob

Comment: I tried `jQuery 1.6.4` and `jQuery mobile 1.0`. Do I need to use [require-jquery.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) instead ?

Comment: I added a link to another (very similar) thread, I think that should solve your problem, check it out.