# RequireJS: Why do relative paths work for define(), but not require()?

Tags: requirejs

Let's say you have the following directory structure, and the following files:

```
root
|-- require-jquery.js
+-- folder
     |-- index.html
     |-- main.js
     +-- AnotherModule.js
```

In RequireJS, when you reference a module starting with a ".", RequireJS looks in the same folder that your current module is in, even if that's a subdirectory. However, if you change baseUrl just before calling define(), RequireJS will map dependencies to the new baseUrl.

You can fix this by setting baseUrl in index.html and changing data-main to a path relative to baseUrl:

folder/index.html:

```
<script>
    var require = {
        baseUrl : "../"
    };
</script>
<script data-main="folder/main" src="../require-jquery.js"></script>
```

folder/main.js:

```
define(
        [ "jquery", './AnotherModule' ],
        function($, AnotherModule) {});
```

This only works for define(), though:

folder/main.js:

```
require(
        [ "jquery", './AnotherModule' ],
        function($, AnotherModule) {});
```

if I try it with require(), RequireJS will look for AnotherModule.js in root, not folder. Why is this, and in particular, why the design difference between define() and require()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because define specifies a module name and require does not.

Define can be called like this:

```
define('folder/main',
        [ "jquery", './AnotherModule' ],
        function($, AnotherModule) {});
```

The first parameter is the module name - an explicit path to the module. Define() always implicitly specifies a path, and in general using an explicit path is [not recommended](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename). Require does not take a name parameter.

When you include a relative dependency in define() (like './AnotherModule'), it's found relative to the module name. In this case, ./AnotherModule would resolve to folder/AnotherModule.

In a call to require(), *there is no module name*. Relative dependencies are resolved to the root.