# RequireJS require() cannot resolve file names at the same subdirectory level

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require, base-url

I've got a directory structure like so:

```
app/
├ js/
│ ├ gui/
│ │ ├ main.js
│ │ └ santa.js
│ └ app.js
└ index.html <- includes requirejs and starts js/app.js
```

**app.js**:

```
baseUrl: 'js' // Pseudo-code for requirejs.config() of course
require('gui/main');
```

So far so good. But every same-dir `require()` in `main.js` gives problems:

**main.js**:

```
require('santa')
```

Tries to `require()` *app/js/santa.js* which does not exist.

```
require('./santa')
```

Tries to `require()` *app/js/santa.js* which does not exist.

```
require('gui/santa')
```

Tries to `require()` *app/js/gui/gui/santa.js* which does not exist.

```
require('./gui/santa')
```

Tries to `require()` *app/js/gui/gui/santa.js* which does not exist.

[image: wtf]

The only way I seem to get my file to be included is like this:

```
require('js/gui/santa.js')
```

which kind of defeats the purpose of name resolving and the `baseUrl` setting.

---

Apart from this weirdness, I'd like to have the `baseUrl` changed to `js/gui` for any `require()` within `main.js`. The configuration is supposed to be extensible and overwritable. But when I do:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl     : 'js/layout'
});
```

within `main.js`, the new setting seems to be ignored like politicians ignore their own promises.

Comment: Weird. Are you sure you put `require('./santa')` in your `gui/main.js` and not in your `app.js`? It should work just fine IIRC.

Comment: Numbering your `require` attempts in `main.js` from 1 to 5, if 1 and 2 happen, then 3 and 4 are not possible *unless* you are passing to RequireJS a configuration that screws up its path resolution logic. (3 should resolve to the same as 1 but with the addition of a single `gui/` element in the path. 4 should resolve to the same as 2 with the same addition.)

Comment: Well, I don't, so there must be a bug in `RequireJS`. Opened an [issue](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1074).

Comment: What does your require do with filenames at a different subdirectory level?

Comment: It adds the subdirectory to the path twice when I request it. See the _app/js/gui/gui/santa.js_ example above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [define instead of require](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename)?

Define can be called like this:

```
define('folder/main',
        [ "jquery", './AnotherModule' ],
        function($, AnotherModule) {});
```

The first parameter is the module name - an explicit path to the module. Normally, you wouldn't include the first parameter - define() always implicitly specifies a path, and in general using an explicit path is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16196409/40352).

Require, on the other hand, does not take a name parameter. It's not possible to do a path relative to a source file with just require()'s and no define()'s, because require does not 'create' a module or define a namespace. Anything require()'d is required **relative to root**.

When you include a relative dependency in define() (like './AnotherModule'), it's found relative to the module name. In the above case, ./AnotherModule would resolve to folder/AnotherModule.

In a call to require(), *there is no module name*. Relative dependencies are resolved to the root.

---

In your case, this would account for the behavior of `require('santa')` and `require('./santa')`. My only guess as to why gui is not acting in the same manner is that, since it includes a subdirectory, it's handled differently. Try using `require('strange-new-directory/santa')` to see if you can get some more insight on the situation.

---

As for baseUrl resetting, baseUrl is, I believe, a global trait and can't be reset midstream (or at least, I wouldn't recommend doing it). You should be able to get relative pathing working with the use of `define`. Good luck.

Comment: If I can just interchange the two, than my understanding of `requirejs` is incorrect or incomplete. The stuff that I `require` are  modules that are `define`d themselves. As far as I know, this is how it is done, and also the way it should work if semantics are supposed to indicate proper usage. Or are you talking about some sort of trick/hack?

Comment: The difference between require and define has to do with how they specify determine pathing. I'll elaborate here but the linked SO question has the necessary information.