# jQuery file upload and RequireJS configuration

Tags: requirejs, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), but I'm getting stuck with the RequireJS configuration. We install our dependencies in a /ext/ folder, e.g:

```
/src
  /ext
    /jquery-file-upload
```

In my main.js I use the following config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "ext/jquery-file-upload": "../ext/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload"
    }
});
require([
    "ext/jquery-file-upload"
]);
```

But then RequireJS tries to load jquery.ui.widget.js from the *root* instead of as a relative file. It is located in the jquery-file-upload directory..

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or does anyone know of a working RequireJS config for jQuery file upload?

Thanks,

Martijn

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the jquery.fileupload.js file, at the top it declares its own dependencies

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
    define([
        'jquery',
        'jquery.ui.widget'
    ], factory);
```

You need to edit your require.config path for the jquery.ui.widget item.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery.ui.widget': 'your_path_here/jquery.ui.widget'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I don't mistake, your problem is that your plugin - jquery-file-upload - tries to load its dependencies by itself.

The problem is that filepaths in JS are relative to the page loading the script file, not to the file itself ([Relative Paths in Javascript in an external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188218/relative-paths-in-javascript-in-an-external-file)). This explains why your file seems to be loaded relatively to the root and not the given path.

In this case, you probably will have to manipulate a bit of the plugin code and take a look at the explanations given here concerning requireJS and dependencies loading:
[How do I use requireJS and jQuery together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535926/requirejs-and-jquery) .

Answer (score 1):

Try mapping jquery.widget.ui to the correct path...

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "ext/jquery-file-upload": "../ext/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload"
        "jquery.ui.widget": "../ext/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget"
    }
});
require([
    "ext/jquery-file-upload"
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem...this is the config that worked for us.Hope it helps someone

**The paths declaration**

```
 paths: { 

        'jquery.ui.widget': '../../Scripts/FileUpload/jqueryui/jquery.ui.widget',
        'jquery_iframe_transport': '../../Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport',
        'jquery.fileupload': '../../Scripts/FileUpload/jquery.fileupload'

    }
```

**The Define statement**

```
define(['jquery.ui.widget','jquery_iframe_transport','jquery.fileupload'])
```

The above is dependent on jquery being loaded. We are using Durandal hence dont need a shim but you will need to ensure jquery is loaded before anything else

The initialisation in code

```
function uploadFile() {


        var url = '/Backload/UploadHandler';

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
                });
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the basic upload example..