# How to connect require.js with jquery.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, requirejs

I have problem with specific piece of code:

```
<script data-main="http://northapp.co/_a/js/main.min.js" src="http://northapp.co/_a/js/require.js"></script>
```

Why can not I connect `require.js` with `jquery.min.js`? I tried following code, but it is not working. Can someone help me?

```
<script data-main="http://northapp.co/_a/js/main.min.js" src="http://northapp.co/_a/js/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add it separately, just like jQuery.

```
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js"></script>
```

After adding requirejs, add the following code inside script tag

```
<script>
 requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
    "app": "../app",
    "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min"
  }
});
</script>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: @Googles : Are you trying to use this https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535926/how-do-i-use-requirejs-and-jquery-together

Comment: Yes but this code idk for what and copy paste at where `requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app",
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min"
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app
requirejs(["app/main"]);`

Comment: At where? Index.html or main.min.js? You can try [link](http://northapp.co). And i hope you can using jquery. Thats without jquery

Comment: yes, you can use it inside index.html, the path set for baseURl, has to be there.

Comment: In your code the path used is "_a/js", so use the same to set for "baseUrl"

Comment: Thats code insert in index.html? You cAn see this, cause that code insert in app.js [link](https://github.com/requirejs/example-jquery-cdn/blob/master/www/js/app.js)